# exported json as string (not array)

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, string

Some have see that code :

```
<?php 
echo stripslashes(json_encode(glob("photos-".$_GET["folder"].'/*.jpg')));
?>
```

it echo a really nice perfect string like that :

```
["photos-animaux/ani-01.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-02.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-02b.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-03.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-04.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-05.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-06.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-07.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-08.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-09.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-10.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-11.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-12.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-13.jpg","photos-animaux/ani-14.jpg"]
```

With json encode it shoul send a array so variable[0] should = to photos-animaux/ani-01.jpg

NOW it is only the fisrt caracter of the string..

how a array get converted to string, and how in javascipt to convert string to array to be able to get value [0] [1] etc..

the question is WHEN or WHY the perfect array get converted to string anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `JSON.parse()`, from the library available [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), is preferable to using `eval()` since this only reads JSON strings and hence avoids the inherant security risks associated with `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse a JSON-encoded string into actual javascript objects, you need to eval() the data returned in order for javascript to execute against the data:

```
var data = eval(json_string)
```

Keep in mind that you should only ever run eval on a string when you trust the source and are sure that there is no possibility of a script injection attack, since javascript will run everything present in the string.

Comment: Don't do this, use a JSON library which will safely evaluate the data, not executing any code.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the JSON libraries listed at the bottom of http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

> WHEN or WHY

If I understood correctly, the answer to both is [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): check out the documentation. Converting a variable to a string (often called *serialization* or *flattening*) is a quite [common operation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).